# Java Development in OpenSUSE

Tags: java, linux, opensuse, suse

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the SUSE.I am not sure about what I am going to do. Please help to review it. Thanks.

If I am going to develop Java application based on the open SUSE. then deploy the Java application to SUSE linux Enterprise Server.Or Vice versa. Does it work fine for both OS platform? I am not sure if there is any compatibility issues for Java development and deployment. Thanks.

**Added**

In my opinion. I think the only thing I should make sure the same on the both platform is the JDK version/bit and the OS version/bit.

In others words. I mean if the deploy environment is JDK 1.7 32bit. then the development environment should keep the same with it (JDK 1.7 32bit).

Is it right? Thanks.

**Added**

In my case .

The Java application will be hosted on IBM WebSphere Application Server version 8.0.x  (Java 1.6.x).
The underlying OS is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64).

Specifically,
Which version of Open SUSE I can use for Java development environment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar scenario using OpenSUSE and SLES. Most of the time it was no problem but sometimes we had strange errors resulting from different Java VMs (HotSpot on OpenSUSE and IBM J9 on SLES).

You should make sure to use the same VM on both machines, not just the same Java version

Comment: +1 Thank you , jpstrube,  So the JVM and JDK is only the care about for this situation ? How about the OS version?

Comment: As I said, the OS version determines the initially installed JVM/JDK versions. But of course you may encounter other problems. I think you will just have to try...